# Obtain a secondary school teaching certificate?

Tags: teaching, application

I am currently taking a year off to reapply for PhDs. My ultimate aim is to work in academia. I am currently teaching secondary school biology as a way of filling this year. My government presents the opportunity of obtaining a teaching certificate by taking weekend classes in addition to the teaching. I was wondering whether a secondary school teaching certificate would be in any way valuable in obtaining a lecturing position after completing my PhD. I know that there are specific university teaching certificates which might mean that a secondary school teaching certificate is useless?

Answer (score 5):

In the big picture, having a secondary school teaching certificate probably won't make a difference in the hiring process for lecturer positions at the university level. Your teaching experience is what will count (to some extent--really, teaching at the collegiate level will be more important), and you will have that to put on your CV. I highlighted my high school teaching experience (and degree, certificate, etc.) on my CV when I applied to teaching positions, and in the interviews I had it was clear that it helped me land the interviews.

That said, if the certificate is something that will give you a fall-back plan if the PhD doesn't work out (i.e., you can transition directly back into the secondary teaching more easily), it might not be a bad idea to get it.

Either way, having the certificate won't hurt you when applying for future collegiate teaching jobs, and if you have the time now it might not be a bad idea to go ahead and knock it out.

Answer (score 3):

Being someone who has a teaching certificate and have just completed my PhD, I can provide some insight to this.  A caveat though, my experience is localised (Australia) and subject based, so not all may be relevant.

My PhD is in Atmospheric Physics, and I am a high school teacher of Maths and Physics, I have been applying to get into lecturing for a little while with no luck, even for STEM and Education lecturing positions.  Having said that, I have only bee searching for a few months.

A colleague was in a similar situation for about 2 years (PhD, high school teaching and applying for academia) and he succeeded, but starting off with short term lecturing contracts (a term here, a term there, then a semester), now he is pretty much part of the furniture in the university faculty.

Talking with my academic supervisor (=advisor) where I asked whether the teaching degree and experience were useless, he suggests that the qualifications and experience are indeed valued, but an academic should build a published research profile and most of all, be patient.

Another thing to note - every degree is not useless, they all contribute to your skills and knowledge in some way at the very least.

As Chris Gregg said, having the teaching qualification can not hurt you, as not only is it a back up - teaching provides bountiful transferrable skills that can be applied in academia, as mentioned in the answer [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10319/progressing-from-high-school-teaching-into-academia).